# If blank text is in textbox then blank action

Tags: jquery, if-statement, textbox

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
if 
    $("#textinput").val("evil");
then
    alert("Watch your language!");
end if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code will set the value of the input

```
$("#textinput").val("evil");
```

You said you wanted to test the current text

```
if ($("#textinput").val() === "evil")
{
    alert("Watch your language!");
}
```